# ajax : load php page and catch errors from that php page on return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/test.php', 
    data: {
        'test': 'phptest'
    }//,
    //dataType : 'json'
}).done(function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);     
    $('#test').html(xhr);
}).fail(function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#test').html(textStatus+': '+errorThrown)
});
```

test.php:

```
<?php

echod $_POST['test'];

?>
```

Notice I purposely use 'echod' so it throws an error.  How can I catch this type of error on return in my done function?

.fail would catch a connection problem to test.php which there isn't.

So, as is, this completes successfully yet my return (xhr) is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE)....` which is the error returned from test.php.  That is what I want to catch.

Comment: it will be catched in the error function. add `error: function(){}` to see

Comment: Don't think you are understanding this right.  I added a little so maybe it is a little clearer now.

Comment: Ignore the accepted answer to the dupe, the second answer shows how you can even catch parse errors. For normal errors you can simply use `set_error_handler()`.